# Is there a way to explicitly set the maximum number of packets tcpdump will capture before terminating?

Tags: tcpdump, maximum, packets

We have a small script that essentially does the following:

```
A) Capture packets using tcpdump and pipe to output file.
B) Run our own clean + sort script on output file.
C) Display results using | sort | etc etc...
```

So, we were wondering if there is a tcpdump parameter that sets the number of packets tcpdump will capture before exiting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcpdump -c [count]` is the option you're looking for.

> -c flag, it will capture packets until it is interrupted by a SIGINT or SIGTERM signal or the specified number of packets have been
> processed.